# Need help on a polymorphism matter

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a simple code, I want to know why and how some methods are chosen over the others :

class A :

```
public class A {
    int f(A aa){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

class B :

```
public class B extends A {
    int f(A aa){
        return 2;
    }

    int f(B bb){
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Test :

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        A ab = new B();
        B b = new B();

        System.out.println(a.f(a));
        System.out.println(a.f(ab));
        System.out.println(a.f(b));

        System.out.println(ab.f(a));
        System.out.println(ab.f(ab));
        System.out.println(ab.f(b));

        System.out.println(b.f(a));
        System.out.println(b.f(ab));
        System.out.println(b.f(b));
    }
}
```

Now, the output of this program is as below :

> 1
>   1
>   1
>   2
>   2
>   2
>   2
>   2
>   3

Now, can you please tell me why `System.out.println(ab.f(b))` gave 2 as output ?

Comment: `System.out.println(ab.f(b))` was linked to -> `A::f(A aa)` but it was override by B

Comment: In the future please use variable names that are easier to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Overload resolution** is done at compile time. **Overrides** are used at runtime.

This means that at compile time, the compiler decides which of all the method signatures is appropriate for the method invocation. Then, at runtime, if that method with that signature is overridden in the run-time object being used, the overridden method is used.

At compile time, only the *static type* of the variable is known. That is, only method signatures that are associated with the *declared* type of the variable are considered.

In this case, the variable `ab` is declared to be `A`. Therefore, only method signatures that exist in `A` are considered for the call `ab.f(b)`. The only `f` in type `A` is the `f(A aa)` method. The call is legal for this method signature, so the code generated by the compiler says "at this point, call the method `f` that has a single parameter of type `A`, and pass `b` as the parameter to it."

When runtime comes, since `ab` is actually a `B` instance, the method `f` that has a single parameter of type `A` is actually overridden in it, so it will print `2`, rather than `1`.

Contrast this with `b.f(b)`. Here the declared type of the variable `b` is `B`. Therefore it has two overloads of the method `f` - one with a `B` parameter and one with an `A`. At *compile* time, it already knows that the argument `b` is declared `B`. So the most specific overload is `f(B bb)`. The invocation is translated into "call the `f` with a single parameter of type `B`". And at runtime, this prints 3.

The difference? At compile time, `ab` was of type `A` and `f(B bb)` doesn't exist in that type. `b` was of type `B`, and `f(B bb)` exists and is the most specific overload.

Comment: Thank you a lot, this makes sense now!

Answer (score 0):

`ab` is an instance of `class B`, as such, it overrides `int f(A aa)` to return 2.

The reason `f(A aa)` is executed, and not `f(B bb)` is that `ab` is a variable of type `A`. As such, there is no `f(B bb)` available to be called so `f(A aa)` is matched (`b` of type `B` inherits `A`).

Although the *value* of `ab` is indeed an object of type `B`, the compiler can't assume that, and certainly can't call functions that don't exist for the declared type of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

ab is a **static variable** of class A. 
while initializing as a dynamic instance of B, the method f in class A is overridden.

Now when calling `ab.f(b)` it "goes" to class A (to the static value) and looks for f ,which now returns 2.